# Optional substrings in PHP with regex

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to parse strings in PHP and store substrings into an array. The format of the string is as follows:

```
@SomeText1 ;SomeText2 $SomeText3 #SomeText4
```

(the "SomeText" substrings will never include the @;$# characters, so that's not a concern)

I want to extract SomeText1, SomeText2, ... separately using PHP, but there's a catch. Everything from the ";" is optional. So some example strings could be:

```
@ SomeText1 ; SomeText2 
@ SomeText1 # SomeText4
@ SomeText1 $ SomeText3 # SomeText4
```

I'm at a complete loss on how to do this.

I've tried searching here for an answer to this but the closest I could find is  ([Matching an optional substring in a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241285/matching-an-optional-substring-in-a-regex)) and ([Regex to capture an optional group in the middle of a block of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408482/regex-to-capture-an-optional-group-in-the-middle-of-a-block-of-input)), but I failed when trying to apply that to my case.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `$array = preg_split('/\s*[;$#]\s*/', $text);`? Add a `@` in there and  ignore the first element if you like that.

Comment: @Qtax PERFECT. Feel free to submit this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$array = preg_split('/\s*[;$#]\s*/', $text);
```

You can also add a `@` in there and ignore the first element if you want to remove it:

```
$array = preg_split('/\s*[@;$#]\s*/', $text);
array_shift($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex in `preg_match` function call:

```
'/@ *(\w+)(?: *; *(\w+))?/'
```

And look for `matches[1] and matches[2]` for your 2 strings (matching groups).

Answer (score 0):

So long as the order is consistent, you can do this:

```
preg_match("((@\S+)\s*(;\S+)?\s*(\$\S+)?\s*(#\S+)?)",$input,$matches);
```

Now, `$matches` is:

```
$matches = array(
    "@SomeText1",
    ";SomeText2" or null if it wasn't there,
    "$SomeText3" or null if it wasn't there,
    "#SomeText4" or null if it wasn't there
);
```

HTH